# Entrypoint in Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker

I made docker image.

I properly copied init.sql script. Additionally I configured database properly. When I ran this command without ENTRYPOINT, inside container, everything works, but when I added this to Dockerfile to ENTRYPOINT and built image again  I see that is showing something like mysql man page. Exited(1). I cant get any logs, what can be wrong with this command?

I think it's not problem of database, but docker itself.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["mysql", "-u", "my_user", "-pmy_pw",  "my_databse", "<", "init.sql"]
```

Comment: You want an image that will only run a single `mysql` client command then immediately exit?  Or are you aiming for something else?

Comment: In init.sql script are many sql commands. I want to run container with mysql image, with init.sql commands, I want to have this container up all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to override the DB container entrypoint, as the entrypoint perform some complex operation like creating DB from mapped init script and set user etc.

All you need to mapp `"init.sql"` with container path `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions `.sh, .sql and .sql.gz` that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), the exec format does not execute a command using the sh or bash shell. So the redirect won't work there.

In order to have that entrypoint working, you should rewrite it:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "mysql -u my_user -pmy_pw my_databse < init.sql"]
```